# Leaflet omnivore

Tags: leaflet, javascript

How to remove the markers from the Leaflet from current layer using the following code:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            //console.log(event.data);
            if (event.data) 
            {
                map.removeLayer(marker);
                console.log(event.data.city_name);
                console.log(event.data.name);
                map.reload();
            }
```

Able to view the printed data but map still remains the same.

```
        window.dataWR = omnivore.csv('ropar_analysis1.csv')
            .on('ready', function(layer) {

                this.eachLayer(function(marker) {

                    //change the icons for each point on the map
                    // marker.setIcon(L.Icon);
                    //create popup text to display the date, city, and country of the GPS data point
                    var popupText = marker.toGeoJSON().properties.location;
                    //bind the popup to each icon
                    marker.bindPopup(popupText);

                    marker.on('mouseover', function(e) {
                        this.openPopup();
                    });
                    marker.on('mouseout', function(e) {
                        this.closePopup();
                    });
                });
            })
            .addTo(map);
```

Comment: How do you know from event which marker you want to remove?

Comment: I WANT TO REMOVE ALL THE MARKERS AFTER THE ON CLICK EVENT FROM PARENT WINDOW